# PHP URI structure for running pages

Tags: php, url, include, uri

Having a custom URI structure for a website rather than every page ending in .php.

If for example I wanted example.com/balderdash to include(balderdash.php) is this how to do it.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == 'balderdash'){ include('balderdash.php') }
```

in the index.php folder?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is "htaccess url rewriting".

Please read this: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php